# Unit Test Fails for Unit Of Work Test

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, unit-of-work

This is my test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestUnitOfWork()
{
    UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();

    unitOfWork.ContactRepository.Insert(new Contact
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        FirstName = "Dom",
        LastName = "A",
        Email = "dominicarchual@yahoo.com"
    });

    var contacts = unitOfWork.ContactRepository.Get(x => x.FirstName == "Dominic");

    Assert.AreEqual(1, contacts.Count());
}
```

The error I get is:

> Test method
>   MvcContacts.Tests.Controllers.HomeControllerTest.TestUnitOfWork threw
>   exception:  System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException: An error
>   occurred while getting provider information from the database. This
>   can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection
>   string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the
>   connection string is correct. --->
>   System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return
>   a ProviderManifestToken string. --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26
>   - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I don't have any database set up; i.e. my context looks like this:

```
namespace MvcContacts.DAL
{
    public class ContactsContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I don't know exactly how to map this to my database; but, I was thinking that I wouldn't have to do that yet since I am just trying to test using mock data.  Am I wrong?

**E1: This is my unit of work class.**

```
namespace MvcContacts.DAL
{
    public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        private ContactsContext context = new ContactsContext();
        private GenericRepository<Contact> contactRepository;

        public GenericRepository<Contact> ContactRepository
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.contactRepository == null)
                {
                    this.contactRepository = new GenericRepository<Contact>(context);
                }
                return contactRepository;
            }
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        private bool disposed = false;

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    context.Dispose();
                }
            }
            this.disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please, post you implementation of UnitOfWork. It seems like you are using real implementation instead of mock one

Comment: @PavelMurygin I assume you mean the definition?  Because, the implementation is right in the test (as it should be, no?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As i said, the problem is that you are actually calling real database inside your `UnitOfWork`. I'm pretty sure, your `GenericRepository<>` class just wraps `DbSet` inside your context. Here is where you create the 'real' database accessor.

```
private ContactsContext context = new ContactsContext();
```

But the problem is you misunderstand the whole concept of repositories. Unit of work is an **abstraction** of some data source. You **should not** unit test the abstraction, instead you should unit test some functionality which depends upon it. By the way, `DbContext` itself is a Unit of work by that definition (from martinfowler.com):

> > Maintains a list of objects affected by a business transaction and coordinates the writing out of changes and the resolution of concurrency problems.

Why don't people just leave it as it is? Because there is a flaw in it. Let me explain by example. Seems like you're learning ASP.Net MVC so let's write some controller:

```
public class ContactsController
{
    public ActionResult Index(int pageSize, int currentPage)
    {
         using(var db = new MvcLearningContext())
         {
             var contacts = db.Contacts
                              .Skip((currentPage - 1) * pageSize)
                              .Take(pageSize)
                              .ToList();
             return View(contacts);
         }
    }
}
```

As you may know, one of the great advantages of MVC is the ability to unit test controller logic. So, let's try to write a simple unit test to make sure out controller action doesn't return more entries than the given page size:

```
[TestMethod]
public void IndexShouldNotReturnMoreThanPageSizeResults()
{
    // arrange
    var controller = new ContactsController();

    // act
    var view = (ViewResult) controller.Index(10, 1);

    // assert  
    var Model = (IEnumerable<Contact>) view.Model;
    Assert.IsTrue(view.Model.Count() <= 10)
}
```

But wait... We **do not** want to query the real database in the unit test. Here comes the problem with EF's `DbContext`: it completely depends on real database. But how can we avoid that? `UnitOfWork` comes in play:

```
public class ContactsController
{
    private UnitOfWorkFactoryBase _factory { get; set; }

    public ContactsController(UnitOfWorkFactoryBase factory)
    {
        factory = _factory;
    }

    public ActionResult Index(int pageSize, int currentPage)
    {
         using(var db = _factory.Create())
         {
             var contacts = db.Contacts
                              .Skip((currentPage - 1) * pageSize)
                              .Take(pageSize)
                              .ToList();
             return View(contacts);
         }
    }
}
```

unit test code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void IndexShouldNotReturnMoreThanPageSizeResults()
{
    // arrange
    var factory = new MockUnitOfWorkFactory();
    var controller = new ContactsController(factory);

    // act
    var view = (ViewResult) controller.Index(10, 1);

    // assert  
    var Model = (IEnumerable<Contact>) view.Model;
    Assert.IsTrue(view.Model.Count() <= 10)
}
```

and in production you replace `MockUnitOfWorkFactory` with `UnitOfWorkFactory`

UPD: basic implementation of factories:

```
public abstract class UnitOfWorkFactoryBase
{
    public abstract UnitOfWorkBase Create();
}

public class UnitOfWorkFactory : UnitOfWorkFactoryBase
{
    public override UnitOfWorkBase Create()
    {
        return new UnitOfWork();
    }
}

public class MockUnitOfWorkFactory : UnitOfWorkFactoryBase
{
    public override UnitOfWorkBase Create()
    {
        return new MockUnitOfWork();
    }
}
```

`UnitOfWork` and `MockUnitOfWork` are implementations of UnitOfWorkBase abstract class.

Comment: Thanks for this info but I am not immediately sure what to change to make my code work.  Probably related: I don't understand where `UnitOfWorkFactory` is defined and how it's supposed to be defined.  Could you please explain these a little more for me?

Comment: You should delete your unit test, it's odd :) Also, you should make an abstract class for unit of work and two concrete implementations, one using DbContext internally and base on in-memory repositories...
Well, that's a whole big topic, drop me a line pavel.murygin@gmail.com. I might be able to help you tomorrow

Comment: I just don't know what `MockUnitOfWorkFactory` and `UnitOfWorkFactory` are supposed to look like.  I've been trying to learn this by following this tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: @user1477388 it's hard to explain everything in one answer. Especially when there are many discussion even among top developers. Here, i've found a nice post on SE: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/11785/ef-code-first-with-repository-unitofwork-and-dbcontextfactory

Comment: I think there's a typo in your `ContactsController` class in the `Index` method: `factory` should be `this._factory`